# ¿Cómo solucionar el siguiente error No : 1071 de Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop1.7

Estoy practicando **PrestaShop** en un hosting gratuito llamado **ByeHost**. Cuando instale la versión **1.6** no hubo problema. Pero ahora que elimine esa versión y cambie por la **1.7**, me arroja el siguiente error, al momento de intentar instalarlo con **Softaculous**:

> **The following errors were found :   Could not make the query numbered : 13   MySQL Error No : 1071   MySQL Error : Specified key
>   was too long; max key    length is 1000 bytes**

Comment: Ejecutando qué cosa te da ese error?

Comment: Cuando intento instarlo mediante Softstaculus

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo para darle solución?

Comment: Pensé que quizá era que las instalaciones anteriores estaban creando algún conflicto, tal vez que como es gratuito el hosting se había llenado el espacio, o quizá que las bases de datos tenían el mismo nombre, así que eliminé todas las bases anteriores , pero sigue arrojando ese error.. Me parece extraño porque se supone que Softaculous hace todo el trabajo por ti.. Sobre todo porque en la versión 1.6 funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 1):

Es un bug en PrestaShop, que en 1.7 parece usar collation utf8mb4 y eso tiene ciertas restricciones en MySQL. Como lo instalas usando un wizard, modificar los scripts no sería una opción.

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/12435

Sugeriría seguir en 1.6.

**Edito:** Revisando otras personas que tienen problemas similares, uno encuentra que:

- Algunos cambian el collation de las tablas y de la base de datos, de `utf8mb4` (que, entiendo, es una buena y más reciente implementación de utf8) a `utf8_general_ci` o similar (que era el viejo utf8 y que está lleno de líos). En general, esta no es una buena idea pues devolverse a viejos formatos con bugs conocidos sólo trae viejos problemas.
- Algunos [se aseguran de usar InnoDB en sus tablas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50689604/236345), que dependiendo de la versión que uses se hace así:

  ```
  set GLOBAL storage_engine='InnoDb';
  ```

  que es para antes de v5.6, o para MySQL 5.6 y posterior:

  ```
  SET GLOBAL default_storage_engine = 'InnoDB';
  ```

  y fijan luego una variable de la BD para que los índices se creen de cierta forma. Corren esto en MySQL antes de correr los scripts de creación de tablas:

  ```
  SET @@global.innodb_large_prefix = 1;
  ```

  para que la longitud máxima del índice sean 3072 bytes.
- La solución apropiada debería venir de los desarrolladores de PrestaShop, pues implica definir los índices [de otra forma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747703/236345), evitando indexar cadenas muy largas.

Comment: No puedo porque estoy siguiendo un tutorial de prestashop 1.7 y veo que muchas cosas del panel han cambiado. ¿y si lo instalo manualmente , sin sofostaculous, crees que funcione?... por cierto que estoy usando el hosting gratuito porque tambien tuve un error con la version 1.7 que instale en mi localhost...si puedes pasa por mi tema que esta en esta misma seccion para ver si me puedes ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: @user137527 Hola. Amplié un poco la respuesta con algunas ideas. Realmente tiene pinta de una implementación descuidada de PrestaShop.

Comment: Pero no entiendo por que a algunos no les pasa.. por ejemplo, el del tutorial que estoy siguiendo, tiene su prestashop 7 corriendo con normalidad. La solucion seria usar localhost entonces, pero ahi tambien tengo un problema, que no me permite entrar al backoffice a pesar de que mi clave es correcta.. recarga la pagina y no entra a ninguns itio

Comment: @user137527 probablemente dependa de la versión de MySQL y la forma en que la instalan por defecto.